# A simpler way to determine the winner in tic-tac-toe?

Tags: alloy

I model the tic-tac-toe game board this way:

```
one sig gameBoard {
    cells: Row -> Col -> Mark -> Time
}
```

Mark is either X or O:

```
enum Mark { X, O }
```

Row and Col are simply sets:

```
sig Row {}{ #Row = 3}
sig Col {}{ #Col = 3}
```

There is a winner when:

- there is a row with all X's or all O's, or
- there is a col with all X's or all O's, or
- there is a left-to-right diagonal with all X's or all O's, or
- there is a right-to-left diagonal with all X's or all O's.

I express that with the following complex predicate. Is there a simpler way to express the winner?

```
 pred winner [t: Time] {
    some m: Mark |
        some r: Row | all c: Col | board[r, c, t] = m
        or
        some c: Col| all r: Row | board[r, c, t]  = m
        or
        board[first, first, t] = m and 
        board[first.next, first.next, t] = m and 
        board[first.next.next, first.next.next, t] = m
        or
        board[last,last, t] = m and 
        board[last.prev, last.prev, t] = m and 
        board[last.prev.prev,last.prev.prev, t] = m
}
```

Here is my complete tic-tac-toe model:

```
open util/ordering[Time]
open util/ordering[Row]
open util/ordering[Col]

/*
Structure:
1. The game is played on a 3x3 board.
2. There are two players, Player1 and Player2.
3. Players mark the game board with either X or O.
4. The game is played over a series of time steps.
*/

// 4. The game is played over a series of time steps.
sig Time {}

// 3. Players mark the game board with either X or O.
enum Mark { X, O }

// 2. There are two players, Player1 and Player2.
enum Player { Player1, Player2 }

// 1. The game is played on a ... board.
one sig gameBoard {
    cells: Row -> Col -> Mark -> Time
} 

// 1. ... on a 3x3 board.
sig Row {}{ #Row = 3}
sig Col {}{ #Col = 3}

/*
Constraints:
1. Each cell has at most one mark (X or O) at each time.
2. A win stops further marking.
3. When all cells are marked, there can be no additional marking.
4. Players alternate moves.
5. There is no interrupt in the play: If cells are empty at time t-1,
     and there is no winner at time t-1, then there will be one
     fewer empty cells at time t. If there is a winner at time t-1,
     then there will be no change to the number of empty cells at
     time t (per invariant 2). 
6. Player1 marks cells O and Player2 marks cells X.
7. When there is a winner or when all cells are marked,
     then the recording of "last player to move" is blank.
*/

// 1. Each cell has at most one mark (X or O) at each time.
pred Each_cell_has_at_most_one_mark {
    no r: Row, c: Col, t: Time, disj m, m': Mark |
        ((r -> c -> m) in gameBoard.cells.t) and
       ((r -> c -> m') in gameBoard.cells.t) 
}

// 2. A win stops further marking.
pred gameBoard_remains_unchanged_after_win {
    all t: Time - first | 
        winner[t.prev] => gameBoard.cells.t = gameBoard.cells.(t.prev)
}

// 3. When all cells are marked, there can be no additional marking.
pred gameBoard_remains_unchanged_after_every_cell_is_marked {
    all t: Time - first | 
        every_cell_is_marked[t.prev] => gameBoard.cells.t = gameBoard.cells.(t.prev)
}

// 4. Players alternate moves.
pred Players_alternately_move {
    no t: Time - last, t': t.next | 
        (some LastPlayerToMove.person.t)  and
        (some LastPlayerToMove.person.t') and
        (LastPlayerToMove.person.t = LastPlayerToMove.person.t')
}

// 5. There is no interrupt in the play: If cells are empty at time t-1,
//     and there is no winner at time t-1, then there will be one
//     fewer empty cells at time t. If there is a winner at time t-1,
//     then there will be no change to the number of empty cells at
//     time t (per invariant 2). 
pred Progressively_fewer_empty_cells {
    all t: Time - first | 
        not every_cell_is_marked[t.prev] and not winner[t.prev] =>
            #empty_cells[t] < #empty_cells[t.prev]
}

// 6. Player1 marks cells O and Player2 marks cells X.
pred Players_mark_cells_appropriately {
    all t: Time - first |
        not every_cell_is_marked[t.prev] and not winner[t.prev] =>
            let c = gameBoard.cells.t - gameBoard.cells.(t.prev) |
                c[Row][Col] = X =>
                   (LastPlayerToMove.person.t = Player2)
                else
                   (LastPlayerToMove.person.t = Player1)
}

// 7. When there is a winner or when all cells are marked,
//      then the recording of "last player to move" is blank.
pred LastPlayerToMove_remains_unchanged_after_win_or_all_cells_marked {
    all t: Time - first |
        ((every_cell_is_marked[t.prev]) or (winner[t.prev])) => 
            no LastPlayerToMove.person.t 
}

// This provides one place that you can call to 
// have all the constraints enforced.
pred game_is_constrained_by_these_constraints {
    Each_cell_has_at_most_one_mark
    gameBoard_remains_unchanged_after_win
    gameBoard_remains_unchanged_after_every_cell_is_marked
    Players_alternately_move
    Progressively_fewer_empty_cells
    Players_mark_cells_appropriately
    LastPlayerToMove_remains_unchanged_after_win_or_all_cells_marked
}

// Return the set of empty cells at time t.
// This is implemented using set subtraction.
// (Row -> Col) is the set of all possible combinations
// of row and col. Subtract from that the set
// of (row, col) pairs containing a mark at time t.
fun empty_cells[t: Time]: Row -> Col {
    (Row -> Col) - gameBoard.cells.t.Mark
}

// Once the game board is completely marked,
// there won't be a "last player." Ditto for when
// there is a winner. That's why there "may" be
// a last player at time t. That is, there isn’t 
// necessarily a player involved at every time step, 
// i.e., there isn’t necessarily a (Player, Time) pair 
// for every value of Time.
one sig LastPlayerToMove {
    person: Player lone -> Time
}

// Return the mark (X or O) on board[r][c] at time t,
// or none if there is no mark.
fun board [r: Row, c: Col, t: Time]: lone Mark {
    gameBoard.cells[r][c].t
}

// There is a winner when (a) there is a row
// with all X's or all O's, or (b) there is a col
// with all X's or all O's, or (c) there is a left-to-right
// diagonal with all X's or all O's, or (d) there is a 
// right-to-left diagonal with all X's or all O's.
pred winner [t: Time] {
    some m: Mark |
        some r: Row | all c: Col | board[r, c, t] = m
        or
        some c: Col| all r: Row | board[r, c, t]  = m
        or
        board[first, first, t] = m and 
        board[first.next, first.next, t] = m and 
        board[first.next.next, first.next.next, t] = m
        or
        board[last,last, t] = m and 
        board[last.prev, last.prev, t] = m and 
        board[last.prev.prev,last.prev.prev, t] = m
}

// Every call of the game board is marked when
// the set of cells with marks equals all combinations
// of (row, col)
pred every_cell_is_marked[t: Time] {
    gameBoard.cells.t.Mark = (Row -> Col)
}

// Initially the game board has no cells.
// One of the players is first to play.
// The game is constrained by the invariants.
pred init [t: Time] {
    no gameBoard.cells.t 
    one p: Player | LastPlayerToMove.person.t = p
    game_is_constrained_by_these_constraints
}

pred doNothing [t: Time] {
    gameBoard.cells.t = gameBoard.cells.(t.prev)
}

pred Play {
    init[first]
    all t: Time - first |
        X.marked_on_gameboard_at_time[t] 
        or O.marked_on_gameboard_at_time[t]
        or doNothing[t]
}

pred marked_on_gameboard_at_time [m: Mark, t: Time] {
    some r: Row, c: Col {
        gameBoard.cells.t = gameBoard.cells.(t.prev) + 
              {r': Row, c': Col, m': Mark | r' = r and c' = c and m' = m}
    }
}

run Play for 3 but 12 Time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

### comment: You can run this whole markdown text in Alloy 5 Beta

## TIC-TAC-TOE

We design this game around a *Board*. The Board is the state and we will use *game rules* encoded in predicates to
constrain the transitions to the next board.

### Setup

Setup the game by defining the board size, the board and the players. The Board has a relative large number
of fields because that makes the trace output nice to read.

```alloy

```
open util/ordering[Board]

let N = 0+1+2
let highest     =   max[N]



sig Board {
    cells : N -> N -> Cell,
    move: Cell,
    to  : N->N,
    won : Cell
}

enum Cell { _, X, O }
```

```

### Winning

The game is won when there is a row, a colum, or a diagonal that holds the same player. We can encode this as follows:

```alloy

```
let rightdiag   =   { r,c : N | r = c }
let leftdiag    =   { r,c : N | c = highest.minus[r] }

pred won[b,b':Board ] {
    some token : X + O {
        let positions = b.cells.token {

                some row    : N | N = row.positions 
            or  some column : N | N = positions.column 
            or  rightdiag in positions
            or  leftdiag in positions

            b'.won = token
        }
    }
}
```

```

### Finished

The game is finished when a player won or there are no more free places.

```alloy

```
pred finished[ b,b' : Board ] {
    not won[b,b'] implies {
        b'.won = _
        _ not in b'.cells[N][N]
    }
    b'.cells = b.cells
    b'.move = _
    b'.to = none -> none
}
```

```

### Play

Plays should alternate between the players. That is why we keep the player in the previous board's `move` field
and check it is not  us. We then constrain the board to have an empty position replaced with the player's
token.

```alloy

```
pred play[b, b' : Board ] {
    b'.won=_
    some token : X+O {
        b.move != token
        b'.move = token
        some row,col : N {
            b.cells[row][col] = _
            b'.cells = b.cells - row->col->_ + row->col->token
            b'.to = row->col
        }
    }
}
```

```

### Trace

Then the only thing remaining is to setup the first board and ensure the game (the trace of *Boards*) is
played according to the rules.

```alloy

```
fact trace {

    first.move = _
    first.won = _
    first.cells = N->N->_

    all b' : Board - first, b  : b'.prev {
        not finished[b,b'] => play[b,b']
    }
}
```

```

### Run

With the *run* we can look for certain types of solutions. In this example we try to find a game where O
wins with a righ diagonal ...

```alloy

```
run { some b : Board | rightdiag in b.cells.(O) } for 11 but 3 int
```

```

This provides the following output in Alloy 5 Table view (table is reorded from beta 5):

```
┌──────────┬──────┬────┬───┬───┐
│this/Board│cells │move│to │won│
├──────────┼─┬─┬──┼────┼───┼───┤
│Board⁰    │0│0│_⁰│_⁰  │   │_⁰ │
│          │ ├─┼──┼────┤   ├───┤
│          │ │1│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          ├─┼─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │1│0│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │1│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          ├─┼─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │2│0│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │1│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│_⁰│    │   │   │
├──────────┼─┼─┼──┼────┼─┬─┼───┤
│Board¹    │0│0│_⁰│X⁰  │2│1│_⁰ │
│          │ ├─┼──┼────┼─┴─┼───┤
│          │ │1│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          ├─┼─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │1│0│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │1│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          ├─┼─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │2│0│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │1│X⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│_⁰│    │   │   │
├──────────┼─┼─┼──┼────┼─┬─┼───┤
│Board²    │0│0│_⁰│O⁰  │1│2│_⁰ │
│          │ ├─┼──┼────┼─┴─┼───┤
│          │ │1│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          ├─┼─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │1│0│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │1│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│O⁰│    │   │   │
│          ├─┼─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │2│0│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │1│X⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│_⁰│    │   │   │
├──────────┼─┼─┼──┼────┼─┬─┼───┤
│Board³    │0│0│_⁰│X⁰  │0│1│_⁰ │
│          │ ├─┼──┼────┼─┴─┼───┤
│          │ │1│X⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          ├─┼─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │1│0│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │1│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│O⁰│    │   │   │
│          ├─┼─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │2│0│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │1│X⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│_⁰│    │   │   │
├──────────┼─┼─┼──┼────┼─┬─┼───┤
│Board⁴    │0│0│O⁰│O⁰  │0│0│_⁰ │
│          │ ├─┼──┼────┼─┴─┼───┤
│          │ │1│X⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          ├─┼─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │1│0│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │1│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│O⁰│    │   │   │
│          ├─┼─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │2│0│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │1│X⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│_⁰│    │   │   │
├──────────┼─┼─┼──┼────┼─┬─┼───┤
│Board⁵    │0│0│O⁰│X⁰  │2│0│_⁰ │
│          │ ├─┼──┼────┼─┴─┼───┤
│          │ │1│X⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          ├─┼─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │1│0│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │1│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│O⁰│    │   │   │
│          ├─┼─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │2│0│X⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │1│X⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│_⁰│    │   │   │
├──────────┼─┼─┼──┼────┼─┬─┼───┤
│Board⁶    │0│0│O⁰│O⁰  │1│1│_⁰ │
│          │ ├─┼──┼────┼─┴─┼───┤
│          │ │1│X⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          ├─┼─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │1│0│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │1│O⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│O⁰│    │   │   │
│          ├─┼─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │2│0│X⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │1│X⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│_⁰│    │   │   │
├──────────┼─┼─┼──┼────┼─┬─┼───┤
│Board⁷    │0│0│O⁰│X⁰  │1│0│_⁰ │
│          │ ├─┼──┼────┼─┴─┼───┤
│          │ │1│X⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          ├─┼─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │1│0│X⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │1│O⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│O⁰│    │   │   │
│          ├─┼─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │2│0│X⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │1│X⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│_⁰│    │   │   │
├──────────┼─┼─┼──┼────┼─┬─┼───┤
│Board⁸    │0│0│O⁰│O⁰  │2│2│_⁰ │
│          │ ├─┼──┼────┼─┴─┼───┤
│          │ │1│X⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          ├─┼─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │1│0│X⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │1│O⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│O⁰│    │   │   │
│          ├─┼─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │2│0│X⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │1│X⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│O⁰│    │   │   │
├──────────┼─┼─┼──┼────┼───┼───┤
│Board⁹    │0│0│O⁰│_⁰  │   │O⁰ │
│          │ ├─┼──┼────┤   ├───┤
│          │ │1│X⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          ├─┼─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │1│0│X⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │1│O⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│O⁰│    │   │   │
│          ├─┼─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │2│0│X⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │1│X⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│O⁰│    │   │   │
├──────────┼─┼─┼──┼────┼───┼───┤
│Board¹⁰   │0│0│O⁰│_⁰  │   │O⁰ │
│          │ ├─┼──┼────┤   ├───┤
│          │ │1│X⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│_⁰│    │   │   │
│          ├─┼─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │1│0│X⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │1│O⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│O⁰│    │   │   │
│          ├─┼─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │2│0│X⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │1│X⁰│    │   │   │
│          │ ├─┼──┤    │   │   │
│          │ │2│O⁰│    │   │   │
└──────────┴─┴─┴──┴────┴───┴───┘
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you @Peter Kriens

Answer (score 1):

I had some fun implementing this example in Lightning. You might find my results interesting:

[image]

Lightning ([lightning-workbench](/questions/tagged/lightning-workbench)) is a language workbench based on Alloy allowing you to define a concrete syntax for any of your Alloy specifications. The concrete syntax is defined through the use of a dedicated model transformation language called [f-alloy](/questions/tagged/f-alloy) ( an Alloy variant having the property of being interpretable rather than analyzable ), so you might need a bit of time getting used to it.

The tool's available as an eclipse plugin ([update site](http://lightning.gforge.uni.lu/update-site)).

Here's [an archive file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oZlRusOz-yZygwrAR7kDcamUcJXsXeqG) containing the source of the TicTacToe project illustrated in the above picture, so that you can play around the example by yourself.

Comment: Wow! That looks great @Loïc Gammaitoni. Is there a standalone version of the lightning-workbench tool? Note: the "update site" you reference says "Document could not be loaded by browser."

Comment: No, unfortunately Lightning was released as an Eclipse plugin, our initial ambition being to connect the Alloy island to the plethora of existing modelling tools based on Ecore.  To install the tool you hence first need to [download Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-modeling-tools/oxygen3a) and then [install the Lightning plugin](https://lightning.gforge.uni.lu/install.html)